# "Permission denied" when `rm` ing a file (in an NFS mount), even when using sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

Context:

- Storage is a Kubernetes Persistent volume, provided by a TrueNAS NAS and accessed via NFS (with k8s accessMode `ReadWriteMany`)
- I have checked the Permissions for the TrueNAS Dataset and confirmed that RWX are set for User, Group, and Other (ack that this is not the most secure, but it's sensitive data on a home network - I would like to "do it right", but that's not a priority)
- Debug pod (mentioned below) is using `ubuntu` image
- There is no `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file on the debug pod, so I assume that SELinux is not involved (though, from the phrasing of that statement, you can probably correctly infer that I'm no expert at SELinux)

I found a file on a mounted NFS drive that was unnecessary and should be deleted. I started up a new pod and mounted the PVC to it, but when  I tried to `rm` the file - even when I used `sudo` - I got permission denied. I also noted the unusual ownership of the file (`nobody`) and tried changing that in case that was the cause, which was also forbidden:

```
$ ls -al
...
-rwxr-xr-x   1 nobody root    1016756 Nov 26 01:21  DELETEME.txt
$ rm DELETEME.txt
rm: cannot remove 'DELETEME.txt': Permission denied
$ sudo rm DELETEME.txt
rm: cannot remove 'DELETEME.txt': Permission denied
$ sudo chown root:root DELETEME.txt
chown: changing ownership of 'DELETEME.txt': Operation not permitted
```

In case this was due to some aspect of Kubernetes, I also tried directly mounting the NFS share (with `-o rw`) to a (non-k8s-pod) machine and carrying out the same commands, with the same results.

What could be preventing `root` from deleting or modifying this file?

EDIT 1 - AFAICT, the NFS share is exported with `777` permissions from TrueNas:

[image: screenshot of TrueNAS UI showing 777 permissions]

and the contents of `/etc/exports` on the TrueNAS box:

```
# cat /etc/exports
V4: / -sec=sys
/mnt/low-resiliency-with-read-cache/ombi-data -mapall="k8s-user":"k8s-user"
/mnt/high-resiliency/k8s/nfs/vols/pvc-cd6d0f5d-a7d0-47a9-8371-29ab9ca27764 -maproot="root":"wheel"
/mnt/high-resiliency/manual-nfs
/mnt/high-resiliency/k8s/nfs/vols/pvc-a485ee75-9413-4b26-abdd-e5c3c23ef7ba -maproot="root":"wheel"
```

Comment: Becoming _root_ on a machine somewhere may not mean much for network storage. Check it directly on the storage server.

Comment: How do you export the share on NFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno what TrueNAS’ web interface does, but I can tell you what your `/etc/exports` says, if the export in question truly is `/mnt/low-resiliency-with-read-cache/ombi-data` (which I kind of doubt, given the other names):

```
-mapall="k8s-user":"k8s-user"`
```

This means that *all* remote users, *root*, not *root*, whatever, are mapped to *k8s-user*. So you can forget about `sudo`, it won’t do anything.

Deleting a file isn’t about modifying the file though, it is about modifying the directory. Unfortunately, your question doesn’t have all information to give a 100% answer. But I bet *k8s-user* does not have write access to the directory containing this file either.

And then there’s also the possibility that Access Control Lists are in use. They go beyond what classic Linux/UNIX file modes do. They could even affect those other exports, which have `-maproot=root:wheel`.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! 1. Yes, `.../ombi-data` _is_ the export in question: the `.../k8s/nfs...` names in `/etc/exports` correspond with volumes that are auto-created by k8s PVCs - e.g. for config directories - whereas for the `.../ombi-data` I explicitly created a k8s PV to NFS mount an existing directory. 2. OK, so it sounds like I need to check the permissions of `k8s-user` _on the TrueNAS box_ - can do! 3. "Deleting a file isn’t about modifying the file though, it is about modifying the directory." TIL, thanks!

Comment: OK, so the easier solution was to just ssh to the TrueNAS box and delete the file directly there. But, thanks to this answer, I now know that any user on a remote server interacting with an NFS-mounted directory would have permissions equivalent to the (TrueNAS-)user `k8s-user`, which explains the fact that permissions on a remote server did not appear to be respected. Thanks!